# Initialize map with pair of std::arrays c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, std-pair, stdarray

I would like to compile this lines. Insert to map pair of std::arrays.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<array>
#include<utility>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  array<double, 8> l;
  array<double, 8> r;
  map<double, pair<array<double, 8>, array<double, 8>>> m;
  pair<array<double, 8>, array<double, 8>> p;
  p = make_pair(l, r);//ok
  m.insert(1., make_pair(l, r));//not ok
  return 0;
}

//clear && g++ getMinPosition.cpp -std=c++11 -o getMinPosition && ./getMinPosition
```

Comment: Please include error text always.  Also, tried emplace?

Comment: You should check the docs for the functions you call: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert - no version takes key_type and mapped_type as separate function arguments.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map to see what value_type is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::map::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) has various overloads, but non accepts two arguments of types as in your code. The closest to your use is the one accepting `const value_type&` where `value_type` is an alias of `pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`.

so instead of :

```
m.insert(1., make_pair(l, r));//not ok
```

do:

```
m.insert(make_pair(1., make_pair(l, r)));
```

or:

```
m.insert({ 1., make_pair(l, r) });
m.insert({ 1., {l, r} });
```

or for better performance use [emplace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/):

```
m.emplace(1., make_pair(l, r));
```

Comment: Worth tacking on a note about why what OP tried wouldn't work: `std::map::insert` expects a `std::pair` of `double` and `pair<array<double, 8>, array<double, 8>>`

Comment: or use `m.emplace(1., make_pair(l, r));`

Answer (score 1):

`std::map::insert()` takes `std::map::value_type` which is `std::pair<const Key, T>`. So you have to do

```
m.insert(make_pair(1., make_pair(l, r)));
```

But I'd recommend to use `emplace()` instead:

```
m.emplace(1., make_pair(l, r));
```

Or even

```
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(1.), std::forward_as_tuple(l, r));
```

so you don't create temporary pairs in-between.